UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT error
I am getting an error when running a script that is supposed to generate a number of wallets and fund then with a certain amount of ETH once they are created.
Error:
ERROR:
reason: 'processing response error',
      code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
      body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":147,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"gas required exceeds allowance (719)"}}\n',
      error: [Error],

Here’s the script that I’m using:
const fs = require('fs');
const { ethers } = require('ethers');


// Replace with the private key of the funding wallet
const fundingWalletPrivateKey = 'REMOVED';
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('REMOVED');


// Number of wallets to create and fund
const numberOfWallets = 100; // Adjust the number of wallets as needed

// Add the funding wallet to the provider
const fundingWallet = new ethers.Wallet(fundingWalletPrivateKey, provider);

async function createAndFundWallets() {
    let walletsData = {};
    const filePath = './wallets.json';

    // Check if wallets.json exists and read its content
    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
        walletsData = JSON.parse(data);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfWallets; i++) {
        // Create a new wallet
        const newWallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
        console.log(`New wallet address: ${newWallet.address}`);
        console.log(`New wallet private key: ${newWallet.privateKey}`);

        // Define the transaction
        const tx = {
            to: newWallet.address,
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.000009'), // Sending 0.000009 ETH
        };

        try {
            // Send the transaction
            const txResponse = await fundingWallet.sendTransaction(tx);
            console.log(`Transaction hash: ${txResponse.hash}`);

            // Wait for the transaction to be mined
            await txResponse.wait();

            // Add new wallet info
            walletsData[newWallet.address] = {
                privateKey: newWallet.privateKey,
                status: 'transferred'
            };

            console.log(`Transaction to ${newWallet.address} completed.`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error sending ETH to ${newWallet.address}:`, error);

            // Add new wallet info with error status
            walletsData[newWallet.address] = {
                privateKey: newWallet.privateKey,
                status: 'error',
                error: error.message
            };
        }

        // Write to wallets.json
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(walletsData, null, 2));
    }

    console.log('All transactions completed and wallet information saved.');
}

createAndFundWallets();

Any help would be appreciated!
